# Grouping values in buckets of maximum size

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of run times for a number of processes and am trying to find the optimal grouping of them, subject to a maximum run time constraint, while trying to minimize the number of groups.

For example, say there is a maximum run time of 20 minutes, and the set of run times in minutes is as follows: [16, 7, 7, 5, 5]

The expected output would be [(16),(5,7),(5,7)], or [(16),(7,7),(5,5)].

Is there a well defined algorithm for dividing things this way?

Comment: Yes, the algorithm is [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can use the [bin packing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) here. Also if we keep a map to track the available space in each bin it would easier to update/add a new bin. Sample working implementation (in Javascript) is given below. Prior to processing each item in array, we can do a sort in descending order to make the solution optimal.

```js
/**
 * Function to give the optimal packing of given items with K constrain.
 * @param {Number[]} array
 * @param {Number} K
 * @return {Number[][]} bins
 * */
function fitIn(array, K) {
  // TODO: Use merge or quick sort here
  array.sort((x,y) => {return y - x; });
  // Resultiing bins
  const bins = [];
  // Map to track available space in each bin in bins array
  const map = new Map();
  
  // Loop through each items
  array.forEach((a, i) => { // O(n)
    // Position where we have to add new item
    let optimalBinIndex = null;
    // Best position mean lowest difference
    let diff = Infinity;
    // Loop through map to find the best bin for given item
    map.forEach((val, key) => { // O(len(map.keys()))
      // We have perfect fit
      if(val == a) {
        optimalBinIndex = key;
        diff = 0;
      } else if(val > a) {
        // If we can fit here update the optimal index
        if(diff > val - a) {
          diff = val - a;
          optimalBinIndex = key;
        }
      }
    });
    
    // No bin is available or perfect for current value
    if(optimalBinIndex == null) {
       const bin = [a];
       bins.push(bin);
       map.set(i, K - a);
    } else {
      // Add to an existing bin
      bins[optimalBinIndex].push(a);
      // Update available space in the map
      map.set(optimalBinIndex, map.get(optimalBinIndex) - a);
    }
  
  });
  // Return all the bins
  return bins;
}


const bins = fitIn([16, 7, 7, 5, 5], 20);
console.log(bins)


const bins10 = fitIn([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 10);
console.log(bins10)
```